# Spacy NER inferring GPE type

Tags: nlp, spacy

When using Spacy for NER, is there a way to extract information  if the entity type is city, country or state when entity type returned is GPE ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of SpaCy models for this, but you can use `geotext` to add some more detail.

```py
from geotext import GeoText

places = GeoText("London is a great city")
places.cities
# ["London"]

# filter by country code
GeoText('I loved Rio de Janeiro and Havana', 'BR').cities
# ['Rio de Janeiro']

GeoText('New York, Texas, and also China').country_mentions
# OrderedDict([(u'US', 2), (u'CN', 1)])
```

For some more flexible uses (such as detecting states), you can also try the [geograpy package](https://github.com/ushahidi/geograpy)

Comment: Interesting. In this case I would use a cascaded approach starting with `SciPy` and then refining the result with `geotext`

Answer (score 1):

No, the default spacy models do not include more fine-grained categories for GPE.